# VBA - Copy two Columns one line of Code

Tags: excel, vba

My line of code looks this way

```
Worksheets("Calculator").Range("AB6:AB16", "AS7").Copy
.Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I want to be able to copy "AB6:AB16" and only the "AS7" cell. so my output would be 
AB6
AB7
AB8
AB9
AB10 and so forth until AB16
..
..
..
and lastly I just want to cell 
AS7..

My current situation is it copies, all the columns to AS, inclusive and my preferable output is the way its described above.

Prior to this one line of code, the output that I would get from 2 lines of code, one to copy "AB6:AB16" and another one to copy "AS7" just gave me wrong results (there is a rand() function that generates numbers that invoke a calculation in AS.

And I realized after trying various structures of the code, that the only time it copies the data correctly is when it happens in one line.

Comment: You can disable calculation whilst the code runs to stop your rand() changing the value with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` as an FYI.

Comment: I want to run this 100000 times, and I need rand() to randomize more numbers every time...
But, if I understood you correctly you say that in between the two lines I can have your line and therefore have it get the correct numbers?

Comment: I dont know what the rest of your code looks like, but at the beginning of your code you can use what I put, do your stuff, and if you are looping 10000's of times, after each run use `Application.Calculate` to get the numbers to change once. Just remember to put it back to normal before you exit the code with `xlCalculationAutomatic`.

Comment: Then in your loop add one line `Application.Calculate` to calculate once before each copy.

Comment: @ScottCraner or after each copy if they want the first value to be the currently visible, but thats just semantics ;)

Comment: Thank you guys! helped me a lot

Comment: In general, you can do `Range("A1").Resize(1,1000).Value = Range("AS7").Resize(1,1000).Value` This will copy the values of the first 1000 columns starting from "AS7" to the columns starting at "A1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from what I understand in your comment that you need to loop and have it change each time you can use something like

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For i = 1 to 1000
    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        .Range("AB6:AB16").Copy .Cells(1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Range("AS7").Copy .Cells(12, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End with
    Application.Calculate
Next i
Application.Calculation = xCalculationAutomatic
```

Completely untested but the idea is there.

**EDIT**

If you are looping columns just be mindful of how many columns are available, if you are looping 10000's of times, depending on your version of excel you may run out (e.g. 2016 has 16384 columns I believe).

Also if you are pasting to the same sheet "Calculator" as your function you will override your `rand()` function as soon as you hit the 28th column.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tim Wilkinson